# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Where: .\flutter.gradle' line: 912 What went wrong: problem occurred evaluating android. problem occurred

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, apk

**I'm new to flutter I got this project and trying to release it, it suppose to be ready for release**

**I tried to build apk out of my flutter App
I tried Flutter build apk
this is the error I got**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Script 'D:\programs\flutter_windows_3.3.7-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912

*** What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildRelease'.
> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [D:\Aqar App\Property\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\release]**

**This is App/build.gradle**

```
  def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '2'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '2.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 33
        buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
    
            applicationId "online.propertyforrent"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 33
           // versionCode "2"
            //versionName "2"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['key.jks']
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    /*
        debug {
               signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
           } */
       }
    
    flutter {
       source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
    //    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
       implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
       implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    }
    
    
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is Android/build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version= '1.8.0'
        kotlin_version= '1.8.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
       /*
      rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
      subprojects {
      project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
       }
    */
      subprojects {
      project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    
    }

**this is gradle-wrapper.properties**

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.2-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.2-all.zip
#ddistributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.2-all.zip
```

**This is pubspec.yal**

```
name: houzi
description: Real estate app
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+4


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.3

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  houzi_package:
    path: packages/houzi_package

#  flutter_icons:
#  run these commands after changing the icon.png in assets/icon
#  flutter pub get
#  flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  remove_alpha_ios: true


flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icon/icon.png
    - assets/no-internet.png
    - assets/settings/dummy_property_image.jpg
    - assets/settings/dummy_property_image_01.jpg
    - assets/settings/dummy_property_image_02.jpg
    - assets/settings/dummy_property_image_03.jpg
    - assets/icon/apple_logo_dark.png
    - assets/icon/apple_logo_light.png
    - assets/icon/facebook_logo.png
    - assets/icon/google_logo.png
    - assets/icon/phone_icon.png


    - assets/localization/en_localization.json
    - assets/localization/ur_localization.json
    - assets/localization/fr_localization.json
    - assets/localization/ar_localization.json
    - assets/localization/ku_localization.json
    - assets/localization/ru_localization.json
    - assets/localization/am_localization.json
    - assets/localization/tr_localization.json
    - assets/configurations/configurations.json



  fonts:
    - family: Cairo
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Cairo/Cairo-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Cairo/Cairo-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Cairo/Cairo-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Cairo/Cairo-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Cairo/Cairo-Light.ttf

    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Light.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Rubik/Rubik-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Regular.ttf

    - family: Ubuntu
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-Light.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf

    - family: Qwitcher_Grypen
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Qwitcher_Grypen/QwitcherGrypen-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Qwitcher_Grypen/QwitcherGrypen-Regular.ttf
```

**flutter doctor -v result**

App\Property> flutter doctor -v
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.7.8 on channel stable at D:\programs\flutter_windows_3.3.7-stable\flutter
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at D:\programs\flutter_windows_3.3.7-stable\flutter. Consider adding
D:\programs\flutter_windows_3.3.7-stable\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 90c64ed42b (10 days ago), 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500
• Engine revision 9aa7816315
• Dart version 2.19.5
• DevTools version 2.20.1
• If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at D:/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-33-ext5, build-tools 33.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

```
     - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
    C++ CMake tools for Windows
    Windows 10 SDK
```

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.147
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

**I tried to many things including changing sdk versions,
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
versions
deleting folders like build etc, cache , I have done almost everything**

Comment: Please Edit your question so everyone can understand. Thank you.

Comment: For posting Gradle build config and command output please use `code` formatting. Also please don't forget to write what you did and what your question is. Just writing a very short question in the title is bad style. In it's current form your question is not readable please correct it.

Comment: Sure, thanks guys, Hope it is easy to read now.